# Why is this loop causing an overflow error?

Tags: c++, loops, overflow

This loop is supposed to add two numbers that are stored in vectors by their individual digits. So, for example leftc will contain [10]{0,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,7} and rightc will contain
[10]{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,9,6} and at the end of the loop `number` should contain "0900000153" (leading zeros are stripped off later in the program). It works perfectly until it gets to index = 0 and then it causes an overflow error, but I can't figure out why.

```
string number;                                                      // accumulates the result of the addition
int num;                                                            // holds the result of adding corresponding elements
short carry = 1;

for ( size_t index = leftc.size() - 1; index >= 0; index-- )        // start from the end of the vectors and work toward the beginning
{
    num = leftc.at(index) + rightc.at(index);                       // add the two elements and store in num
    if ( num >= 10 )
    {
        num %= 10;
        leftc.at(index - 1) += carry;
    }
    num += '0';                                                     // convert num from int to char                                             
    number.insert( number.begin(), num );                           // store num at front of number
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: When index is 0, `leftc.at(index - 1)` you are indexing -1 here

Comment: And don't forget that since `index` is unsigned, `index >= 0` is always true.  You compiler probably should have issued a warning about that.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Ok, in that case `index-1` will be MAX_VALUE(size_t) ~ 2^32-1, which is definitely out of range

Comment: But num >= 10 never evaluates to true when index = 0 because the leading zero is just there in case a carry is required when the second elements are added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a problem here

```
for ( size_t index = leftc.size() - 1; index >= 0; index-- )
```

As `size_t` is unsigned, `index` will *always* be `>=0`.

Comment: This fixed it! I never would have guessed... Thank you so much!

Comment: @JamesGold: It will be interesting is see HOW did you fixed it: is one of the pattern that is mostly debated by language lawyers ...

Answer (score 1):

When your `index` is 0 your `(index-1)` will be -1...hence its giving an overflow error...because you are trying to access an item at index "-1".

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( num >= 10 )
{
    num %= 10;
    leftc.at(index - 1) += carry;
}
```

In here you get an error if index is zero - you access the (-1)-th element.